como hago para que estos imputs sean de opcion multiple? osea si los selecciono todos me llega solamente 1
Tengo un formulario donde se eligen las vacantes que las personas quieren aplicar para mi emprendimiento pero no encuentro la forma de que sea opción múltiple, él me recibe, pero solo selecciona 1, agradeceria quien me puede ayudar o explicar.
Además también borre muchas lineas de codigo <div> porque no me dejaba formular la pregunta pero lo esencial del formulario aqui esta
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=\, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <title>Document</title>
    </head>
  <body>

<form action="guardar.php" method="POST">
                                                   
<input type="checkbox" name="jobsearch3" value="Mantenimiento Landscape"/>
<label class="ml-10" for="jobsearch3" >  Mantenimiento Landscape </label>
 

<input type="checkbox" name="jobsearch3" value="Instalación Landscape"/>
<label class="ml-10" for="jobsearch3" >  Instalación Landscape </label>
 
                       

<input type="checkbox" name="jobsearch3" value="Irrigacion Landscape"/>
<label class="ml-10" for="jobsearch3" >  Irrigación Landscape </label>

                            
<input type="checkbox" name="jobsearch3" value="Limpieza"/>
<label class="ml-10" for="jobsearch3" >  Recepcionista Landscape (Front Desk) </label>

                           

<input type="checkbox" name="jobsearch3" value="Limpieza"/>
<label class="ml-10" for="jobsearch3" >  Limpieza (Cleaning) </label>


<input type="submit" value="Enviar Formulario">
</form>

</body>
</html>     

         


jobsearch3 es un nombre de variable única, si le llamas jobsearch3[] será un array y php lo podrá leer como tal. Es conveniente investigar antes de pregunta, una simple búsqueda en google de "php multiple checkbox" te arroja 100 páginas con la solución a este problema.

si todos los elementos tienen el mismo atributo name, solo el ultimo en ser cargado en el DOM sera enviado que los request ... puede usar al final del nombre la estructura de array: "[]" pero esto no ayudara a saber cual es el comanpo exactamente enviado.

eso es justamente lo que me pasa Fransico, no se exactamente cual campo es enviado si uso el array:"[]"

Lo que necesitas hacer es cambiar los atributos name="" de los <input> dado que la estructura que tienes, como todos tienen el mismo nombre exacto, sólo te enviará el valor del último seleccionado.
Tienes que cambiar los name="" para que sean un array. De esta manera, cuando se envíe el formulario, todas las opciones seleccionadas se enviarán como un conjunto de valores.
Aquí está cómo puedes hacerlo:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="guardar.php" method="POST">
    <input type="checkbox" name="jobsearch[]" value="Mantenimiento Landscape"/>
    <label class="ml-10" for="jobsearch3" >Mantenimiento Landscape</label>

    <input type="checkbox" name="jobsearch[]" value="Instalación Landscape"/>
    <label class="ml-10" for="jobsearch3" >Instalación Landscape</label>

    <input type="checkbox" name="jobsearch[]" value="Irrigacion Landscape"/>
    <label class="ml-10" for="jobsearch3" >Irrigación Landscape</label>

    <input type="checkbox" name="jobsearch[]" value="Recepcionista Landscape (Front Desk)"/>
    <label class="ml-10" for="jobsearch3" >Recepcionista Landscape (Front Desk)</label>

    <input type="checkbox" name="jobsearch[]" value="Limpieza (Cleaning)"/>
    <label class="ml-10" for="jobsearch3" >Limpieza (Cleaning)</label>

    <input type="submit" value="Enviar Formulario">
</form>

</body>
</html>




Si todos los inputs tienen el mismo name puedes obtener los valores de cada checkbox usando querySelectorAll('input[name="jobsearch3"]') y luego insertarlos en un array de js y con un listener monitorear los cambios según la selección del usuario, algo asi:


// Obtener todos los checkboxes con el mismo nombre
const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="jobsearch3"]');

// Función para obtener los valores seleccionados
function obtenerValoresSeleccionados() {
  const valoresSeleccionados = [];
  checkboxes.forEach(checkbox => {
    if (checkbox.checked) {
      valoresSeleccionados.push(checkbox.value);
    }
  });
  return valoresSeleccionados;
}

// Agregar un event listener a cada checkbox
checkboxes.forEach(checkbox => {
  checkbox.addEventListener('change', () => {
    const valoresSeleccionados = obtenerValoresSeleccionados();
    console.log('Valores seleccionados:', valoresSeleccionados);
  });
});
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=\, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <title>Document</title>
    </head>
  <body>

<form action="guardar.php" method="POST">
<input type="checkbox" name="jobsearch3" value="Mantenimiento Landscape"/>
<label class="ml-10" for="jobsearch3" >  Mantenimiento Landscape </label>
<input type="checkbox" name="jobsearch3" value="Instalación Landscape"/>
<label class="ml-10" for="jobsearch3" >  Instalación Landscape </label>
<input type="checkbox" name="jobsearch3" value="Irrigacion Landscape"/>
<label class="ml-10" for="jobsearch3" >  Irrigación Landscape </label>
<input type="checkbox" name="jobsearch3" value="Limpieza"/>
<label class="ml-10" for="jobsearch3" >  Recepcionista Landscape (Front Desk</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="jobsearch3" value="Limpieza"/>
<label class="ml-10" for="jobsearch3" >  Limpieza (Cleaning) </label>
<input type="submit" value="Enviar Formulario">
</form>
</body>
</html>



